# Google NLP API - Companies identified as "Unknown"

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl, google-natural-language

I try to identify entities in French newspaper articles and very often organizations, even famous ones such as Apple, are identified as "Unknown", whereas the linked Wikipedia page is correct.

You can try using the content of this article:
http://www.lefigaro.fr/secteur/high-tech/2018/02/02/32001-20180202ARTFIG00030-trimestre-record-pour-apple-grace-a-ses-prix-eleves.php

Does anybody know how to make sure companies are correctly recognized as "Organization" entities?

Comment: Have you tried to set the language to French in your request?

Comment: Using this article content and the [Google demo](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/), Apple is recognized as an Organization. I then tried the URL (removing the dashes) and apple (no caps) is not recognized (Unknown). Which method are you using against the API ?

Answer (score 0):

I work on this API at Google. This turned out to be a bug and we've fixed it. Please try again.